# specs2 await tests play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I have methods returning Future[T] and I have a test setup following way

```
 methodReturningFuture should beEqualTo(\/-()).await(timeout = 1000.milli)
 listSize must equalTo(testSize)
```

When I run this test **alone** it works fine but

when running all the tests together it appears that `await` has no effect and test keeps failing on `equalTo` comparison for the line below it as it appears test isn't waiting for future to complete and straight goes into comparing on a next line.

I have standard build.sbt which runs all the test. note; I also have `parallelExecution in Test := true` in the build file.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but I would start be decomposing what specs2 is doing. Look at the `.await` code (a call to `Await` then `Thread.sleep` and a possibly a retry) and inject it in your example to put specs2 code away.

Comment: Are you using mutable specifications?

Comment: @Huw yes: I use mutable.Specification. do you think anything related to that's causing this behavior while running all the tests together?

Comment: You can test this by mixing in the `org.specs2.matcher.NoThrownExpectations` trait (and use `and` to chain expectations)